# Protocol C is unknown error in qml

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a qml file , here is the source code:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Image
{
    id: imageIcon;

    width: 100;
    height: 100;

    source: 'C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Chrysanthemum.jpg';
}
```

When I display it on a QQuickView i get this error:

> QML Image: Protocol "c" is unknown

I am running the code on Windows 7 if it is relevant.

What is the correct format of the url?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like source must use a correctly formatted URL : it's either expecting a `file://` scheme or a `qrc://` (for stuff inside Qt resources)

Parsing of your files tries to use a "C" protocol (from C:/) which is unknown : try

```
source: 'file:///C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Chrysanthemum.jpg';
```

See : http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/platform-api-reference/xml/daily-docs/libqt4/qml-url.html

Usually you want to have your images relative (deployed near your app) or embedded into resources, not references absolutely as this will break deployment.

Comment: actually qrc works for me, if i give the url like 'qrc:/img/vista-manage-folders-icon.jpg' it works. However i want to give the url dynamically because i am going to use it for file explorer, so image files are not going to be defined in qrc.

Comment: Then it's not static but dynamic. Native Qt (C++) has a method to transform local files into URL : http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qurl.html#fromLocalFile